# Programmatically monitor URLSession requests

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

How to programmatically monitor all incoming and outgoing requests that my app is making using `URLSession`?

The goal is to see data like URL, headers and body of those requests.

Perhaps something [similar to this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/analyzing_http_traffic_with_instruments) but using code within my app.

This should work in production and should be able to listen to the requests made by third party libraries, too.

Comment: Maybe look for "URLSession Interceptor", with `Interceptor` being a keywork for your search, then you might be able to print all the needed infos of `URLRequests`. Alamofire has its own Interceptor, and I use it to print all theses infos when needed.

Comment: depends very much how your app creates URLSessions, and do you need to monitor  sessions of 3rd-party libraries or not, whether this is for internal use or production... One pretty universal way would be to do something similar to OHHTTPStubs (https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/tree/master/Sources/OHHTTPStubs) which can catch all the traffic, but it's overwriting some defaults, so not a good idea for prod.

Comment: @khjfquantumjj edited the question to answer your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to see data like URL, headers and body of those requests

If you want to track only *requests* (but not responses), then it's as simple as adding an extra layer of `NSURLProtocol` to the session object. Since public API of the `NSURLSession` accepts tasks only, you can limit tracking to [`canInitWithTask:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocol/1416997-caninitwithtask) method:

```objc
@interface TDWWatcherProtocol : NSURLProtocol

@end

@implementation TDWWatcherProtocol

#pragma mark NSURLProtocol

+ (BOOL)canInitWithTask:(NSURLSessionTask *)task {
    [self p_printRequestData:task.originalRequest];
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    // no-op
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark Private

+ (void)p_printRequestData:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"==========================");
    NSString *httpMethods = request.HTTPMethod ? request.HTTPMethod : @"GET";
    NSLog(@"Request: %@ %@", httpMethods,  request.URL);
    NSLog(@"Headers: %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
    if (request.HTTPBody && request.HTTPBody.length) {
        NSLog(@"Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}

@end
```

You cannot omit implementation of [`canInitWithRequest:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocol/1411389-caninitwithrequest) because in this case URL loading system will forward it to the base implementation of `NSURLProtocol`, which throws an error (the class is considered abstract). You provide your custom protocol to a `NSURLSession` instance by incorporating it to the configuration's [`protocolClasses`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411050-protocolclasses?language=objc) property:

```objc
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
NSMutableArray<Class> *protocolClasses = [configuration.protocolClasses mutableCopy];
[protocolClasses addObject:[TDWWatcherProtocol class]];
configuration.protocolClasses = protocolClasses;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

If you additionally want to track all requests made by the [`sharedSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1409000-sharedsession) instance you must register your class globally with `NSURLProtocol` helper methods:

```objc
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[TDWWatcherProtocol class]];
```

This also makes URL loading system to forward web views to requests to your protocol class.

---

You may want to track `canInitWithRequest:` invocations as well, but be advised that in this case you will also get modified requests from internal implementation in addition to the original requests.

Answer (score -1):

you can have a look at the source of `Moya`.
[image]

Comment: "have a look at" doesn't answer the question. You need to provide details or implementation sample comprehensive enough to reproduce it in an arbitrary project